# XHR responseType = 'arraybuffer' が Firefoxで動かない

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
function getAudio(aUrl) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // ajax is not capable of arraybuffer
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.open('GET', aUrl, true);

    // request succeeded
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (
            (xhr.readyState === 4) && 
            (xhr.status === 200) && 
            (xhr.status !== 404)
            ) {
            audioCtx.decodeAudioData(xhr.response, function(buffer) {
                buf = buffer;
                return deferred.resolve(true);
            });
        } 
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        return deferred.resolve(false);
    };
    xhr.send();
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

responseTypeが'arraybuffer'のXMLHttpRequestを送るメソッドを作りました。
Chrome, Safariでは動きます。しかしFirefoxだと
'InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable'
というエラーが出ます。

Mozillaのサイトサンプルでも上記と同じ方法でxhrをリクエストしています。
何が問題でしょうか。

引数aUrlは"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/121818867/stream?client_id=8f474de4d1dedd5a6a4f4cbb60f4e6b8"
といったものです。（localではない）

Comment: firefoxのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

次のコード部分

```
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.open('GET', aUrl, true);
```

を次のように処理順序を入れ替えて試してみてください。

```
xhr.open('GET', aUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

一時期の仕様案では、`XMLHttpRequest` の state が `OPENED` でない場合に `responseType` をセットすると`InvalidStateError` を投げるようになっていました。

[現在の仕様案(2014-01-30〜)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/#the-responsetype-attribute)では state が `LOADING` か `DONE` の場合に `InvalidStateError` を投げるようになっています。

> When set: throws an "InvalidStateError" exception if the state is LOADING or DONE.

最新の仕様案と Firefox の実装が異なるということだと思います。